# Could not initialize class java.util.logging.LogManager

Tags: java, spring, cxf

Why do I get this error. I get it in my develpment tool when I run my code as a java application (IBM RSA\Eclipse) and in my isolated deployment environment. 
I can run junits against the code and they are successful so I know that parsing the particular application context file is not a problem (web service application context). The same jre and maven dependencies are on the classpath for junit and running java application.
I know cxf uses java logger by default but adding this command doesn't help,

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.Logger",   "org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger");
```

If I debug the code I see that the issue is raised when the application context files are parsed.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid      NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for     namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not    initialize class java.util.logging.LogManager

Comment: It seems that you are missing a spring jar on the deployment classpath. Check that you have into the deployment all the jars used in the junit

Comment: I'm using Maven to the same jars are used in both situations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add this System property and provide the default file when running as a java app.

System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "/log/logging.properties");

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=143

Now I have another problem but similar in nature so hopefully  I can find a similar solution.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.ProxySelector